# React Native Expo eas build - Execution failed for task ':expo-location:compileReleaseKotlin'

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I'm using eas build on android and run into this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':expo-location:compileReleaseKotlin'.
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction

Task :expo-location:compileReleaseKotlin FAILED
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/LocationModule.kt:734:63 Unresolved reference: UPSIDE_DOWN_CAKE
e: file:///home/expo/workingdir/build/node_modules/expo-location/android/src/main/java/expo/modules/location/LocationModule.kt:735:95 Unresolved reference: FOREGROUND_SERVICE_LOCATION
```

My App.json:

```json
"expo-build-properties",
          {
            "android": {
              "usesCleartextTraffic": true,
              "compileSdkVersion": 33,
              "targetSdkVersion": 33
            }
          }
```

I tried change sdk version to 31 but getting same error